# Ask user for 5 numbers then add together for total using a loop

Tags: c#

```
using System;
 class SumDoubles
 {
    static void Main()
    {   
        //Declare variables
        double DblSumTotal = 0;
        double LIMIT = 0;


        //Ask user to input 5 numbers to be added
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 numbers to be added together.");
        do 
        {
            DblSumTotal = DblSumTotal + (Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));
            LIMIT = LIMIT + 1;
        } while (LIMIT < 6);

        //Output total
        Console.WriteLine("The total sum of the 5 numbers is " + DblSumTotal);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }   
}
```

This is the code I have so far. It will compile but I receive an error when trying to run it:

> Unhandled Exception: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormat Info numfmt) at System.Double.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider) at SumDoubles.Main()"

I am very new to coding and I can't seem to wrap my head around loops. Please help!

Comment: The input will be numbers. I usually try adding 5 1s together. The output should be "The total sum of the 5 numbers is 5" but I receive an error

Comment: Where am I converting wrong?

Comment: are you pressing return after each input number? it sounds like you might not be using the program the way you coded it to work

Comment: Are your 1s simply typed as `1` or you're including decimals (`1.00`)?

Comment: The errormessage says that the input was something it didn't recognise. Try first with integers, then use `double.TryParse`.

Comment: Just "1" and then return

Comment: as a side note, the way you have your loop it actually requires 6 numbers instead of 5... since do while() evaluates the expression at the end. i think a while loop or a for loop would be more appropriate here

Comment: Oh and try to break up your statements so you can set-up a breakpoint and see what's going on exactly.

Comment: when you say, just "1" and then return, are you actually including the quotes? if so that's the problem

Comment: no.. i am not including the quotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Sasse and Tejas Sharma have a point. Complete code might then look something like this:

```
 using System;
 class SumDoubles
 {
    static void Main()
    {   
        //Declare variables
        double DblSumTotal = 0;
        double LIMIT = 0;


        //Ask user to input 5 numbers to be added
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 numbers to be added together.");
        do 
        {
            double d;
            if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out d)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Format error!!!");
            } else {
                DblSumTotal = DblSumTotal + d;
                LIMIT = LIMIT + 1;
            }

        } while (LIMIT < 5);

        //Output total
        Console.WriteLine("The total sum of the 5 numbers is " + DblSumTotal);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }   
}
```

`
Also, if you, like me are using non-English locale (I have a Czech system), then the string that can be parsed to double looks a bit different (i.e. Czech "1,2" vs English "1.2")

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToDouble` throws the exception you're seeing when it gets bad input e.g. an empty string. You probably either want to handle the exception using a `try catch` block or you could alternatively use [`double.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) which doesn't throw in the face of bad input.

```
double output;
bool isValid = double.TryParse("10", out output); // isValid is true and output contains 10
isValid = double.TryParse("lsdf", out output); // isValid is false
```

I also noticed that you have an "off by 1" error in this code

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 numbers to be added together.");
do 
{
    DblSumTotal = DblSumTotal + (Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));
    LIMIT = LIMIT + 1;
} while (LIMIT < 6);
```

Your loop has 6 iterations (LIMIT = 0,1,2,3,4,5) and you are expecting 5 numbers. You're probably pressing an extra "enter" which is causing an empty string `""` to get passed to `Convert.ToDouble` and thus leading to the exception. Change `while (limit < 6)` to `while (limit < 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program works just fine, except it reads six numbers instead of five.

I think your problem is related to what xeraphim is saying, you're trying to input all the numbers at the same time.

If you type "4" ENTER "5" ENTER "10" ENTER and so on, it will work just fine. =)

PS: Remember that there's a difference between "." and ",".

Comment: This is what I am doing I type 1 and then enter 5 times and receive the error

Comment: As I said, it expects you to do it six times as it is now. So if you the last time are just pressing "ENTER" then it will take your empty string and try to convert it, which will fail and though throw the exception.

Comment: @LeFemur 'type 1 and enter' 5 times, or type 1 and then 'enter 5 times'? Because an empty statement will create the exception. And you can just set a breakpoint and debug it..

Comment: So how do i make it just display the total without having to press enter? and why is it accepting more than 5 answers when i have a limit set?

Comment: Oh, ny bad. You've changed the row "while (LIMIT < 6)" to "while (LIMIT < 5)" now. When I copied you code there was a 6 there instead of a 5. I don't understand your question. You type something and then press ENTER which makes the program knows that you're done with your input. Now I can see you've changed the code quiet a bit, I'll try the new code and then answer. I think I'm tired, I looked at Oskar Hybl's code example which worked just fine. Well, change you while (LIMIT < 6)" to "while (LIMIT < 5)" and try again and then mark the best answer as "answer". =)

Answer (score -2):

I think this can be simplified by using a for loop.

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace ConsoleApplication2
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    int read;
                    int sum = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 numbers: "); 
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                       read = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                       sum = sum + read;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("The total sum of the 5 numbers are " + sum);
                }
            }
        }
```

Or if you still want to use while loops it just as easy.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int read;
            int sum = 0;
            int i = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 numbers: "); 
            while(i<5)
            {
               read = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
               sum = sum + read;
               i++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The total sum of the 5 numbers are " + sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's question is about failing due to incorrect format, how does simplification of the loop helps?

Comment: No it's okay this was very helpful too. You all probably realized this was for a school assignment too